# ¿Por qué no se imprimen todos los Log.d() en el logcat?

Tags: android-studio, logcat

Tengo una app y estoy usando `Log.d(tag, mensaje);` para imprimir mensajes y poder identificar donde falla mi código.

La cuestión es que cuando ya tengo muchos Log(especialmente si estos están dentro de un bucle) y agrego nuevos, los nuevos ya no me aparecen en el logcat.

Para solucionar lo antes mencionado,  que he hecho es quitar todos los log que ya no necesito y dejar solamente los nuevos.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Este problema sucede generalmente porque imprimimos una gran cantidad de información (Se tiene un limite para la información contenida en la ventana) y no se tiene definido un filtro.

Lo que sucede es que no se puede contener toda la información en la ventada de `LogCat` , más aún si se esta imprimiendo información del sistema y estos mensajes son considerables:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo recomendable en esta situación es configurar el `LogCat` para que únicamente muestre información de tu Aplicación, mediante la opción  `"Show only selected application"`:

> `Show only selected application`: se muestran los mensajes producidos
>   por el código de la app únicamente (configuración predeterminada). El
>   monitor de logcat filtra los mensajes de registro mediante el PID de
>   la app activa.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

También puedes editar tu propio filtro o en este caso además de mostrar únicamente mensajes de tu aplicación puedes también filtrar mediante un Tag especifico:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Para más información revisa la documentación oficial:
[**Escribir y ver registros con Logcat**](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/am-logcat?hl=es-419)